# What's the difference between substitution and piping to bash

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I am running these two commands:

```
echo $(find ./ $OPT1 $OPT2 $OPT3)
echo find ./ $OPT1 $OPT2 $OPT3 | bash
```

and the weird thing is, the top command yields no results while the bottom one does. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The first runs `find ./ $OPT1 $OPT2 $OPT3` word-splits and globs the output (no quotes around `$()`), and passes it to `echo`, which prints it. Which is mostly the same as just running the `find` command, but newlines get turned to spaces, and if any file names printed by `find` contain `*` or `?`, they'll be expanded. Though if your `IFS` contains something unusual, the word-splitting will be similarly unusual. (Also, `$OPT1` and others are also not quoted, so they're split and globbed before passing to `find`.)

The second prints `find ./ $OPT1 $OPT2 $OPT3`, expanding the variables (again splitting and globbing, because no quotes), and passes the result to `bash`, which runs it as a command. Again pretty much the same as just running the `find`, but if the variables contain shell metacharacters, they'll be expanded (again) by the second shell.

The first one, note that the filename `foo*` is expanded, globbing the all three:

```
$ touch foo1 foo2 foo\*
$ echo $(find .)
. ./foo2 ./foo* ./foo1 ./foo2 ./foo1
```

The second, note that the pipe to bash causes the inner variable to be expanded, like if you used `eval` :

```
$ OPT='echo $BASH_VERSION'
$ echo $OPT
echo $BASH_VERSION
$ echo $OPT | bash
4.3.30(1)-release
$ eval $OPT        # about the same  
4.3.30(1)-release
```

Variable expansion is probably the simplest example of this, but it needs an exported variable or one that the other shell has in any case, like `BASH_VERSION` here. (I can't come up with a sane example with `find` for now.)

Depending on what your `OPT` variables contain, the extra eval round might make the difference in if `find` matches anything.