# Difference between piping and command expansion

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution

This link is relevant [What's the difference between substitution and piping to bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310646/whats-the-difference-between-substitution-and-piping-to-bash) but I am not quite understanding everything that is being said.

What is the difference between piping `command1 | command2` versus expanding commands `command2 $(command1)`? For example

```
vi $(find /home | grep xyzzy)
```

spits results out to vi to edit whereas

```
find /home | grep xyzzy | vi
```

doesn't seem to work for me. But I'm not understanding the fundamental difference.

## Edit

Other relevant posts

[Process substitution and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe#17117)

[Process substitution and pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe)

Comment: additionally, if the file names have spaces in them, [the command expansion will not work](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/mdk3bc/bash_script_for_loop_failing_on_spaced_file_names/). you could use `find /home | grep xyzzy | xargs -i vi {}` to "fix" this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A|B
```

executes A and B (in parallel), and the standard output of A is fed into the standard input of B. In the case of

```
A $(B)
```

the shell executes first B, collects the standard output of B, then executes A, but for this execution assigns the individual word's to the ARGV-vector of A (i.e. A can access these words by the usual argv mechanism known from C and other language).

Aside from the fact that in both cases two programs A and B are involved, I don't see anything similar between them.

Comment: In what shell are piped commands run in parallel? How could that even occur? B has to read A's output (as B's input), which, as far as I'm aware, means A needs to produce an output before B can read it. Additionally, the line that could produce similar behavior using command substitution would be: `B $(A)`, not `A $(B)`, which is the OPs question.

Comment: @DeNovo : If you have pipe `A|B`, the usual implementation is to start both processes A and B, and feed the stdout of A to the stdin of B. Without this, a construct such as `A|tail -f`  would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The first expands to `vi <list_of_filenames>`.

The second directly pipes the filenames to `vi`. Presumably, `vi` won't work like this. You can certainly pipe text to `vim`, but that is interpreted as the text to process, not the filename itself. (You's have to use `vim -`. See `man vim` for more information.)

Comment: why not using `xargs`?

Comment: @cregox Because that's not the question?

Comment: then you don't **have to** use vim, at very least! 

Comment: @cregox I _think_ the question is really about the differences between piping and command substitution. The `find` part is just a dummy command to produce example output, as a proof of concept. They don't necessarily want to pipe the output of `find`.

Comment: no matter how i look at it, i still find it very misleading to point the issue in his instance might be with vi, rather than with the difference between piping and command expansion, specially when xargs is specifically made to deal with this.